# Why can't I convert concrete type to interface while using generic constraints

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I have a code structure like below

```
interface IAnimal 
{
    string name;
    int Age;
}

class Tiger : IAnimal
{
    public string name;
    public int Age;
}

class Dog : IAnimal
{
    public string name;
    public int Age;
}
```

extension class is below

```
public static class AnimalExtension
{
    public static TAnimalType ConvertTo<TAnimalType>(this Animal animal) where TAnimalType : IAnimal
    {
        TAnimalType concreteAnimal;
        if (animal.Name == "tom")
        {
            concreteAnimal = new Tiger(); // compiler error at this line
        }
        return concreteAnimal;

    }
}
```

Error : Can't implicitly convert Tiger to TAnimal

Why is the compiler not able to convert Tiger(this class implemented IAnimal) to TAnimal. This seems to be a problem while using generic constraints.

While the below code works fine..

```
IAnimal myTiger = new Tiger();
```

Comment: There's a difference between `TAnimalType` and `IAnimal` -- you're comparing an interface with a generic type representation.

Comment: Why not make `ConvertTo` non-generic and make it return `IAnimal`?

Comment: Because your implementation as it is right now could make something like this: `Dog concreteAnimal = new Tiger();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have:

```
class Tiger : IAnimal
```

and elsewhere a constraint:

```
where TAnimalType : IAnimal
```

and then you go:

```
TAnimalType concreteAnimal;
// ...
concreteAnimal = new Tiger(); // compiler error at this line
```

But all we (and the compiler) know is that both `Tiger` and `TAnimalType` implement the same interface. **That does not imply any relation what so ever between `Tiger` and `TAnimalType` themselves!**

For example `TAnimalType` could legally be a `Dog`. In that case you would be putting a `Tiger` into the `Dog` variable `concreteAnimal`. That is not allowed.

Answer (score 4):

Because `TAnimalType` could be any animal type, even `Dog`.  If someone called `ConvertTo<Dog>()`, the code you've written would look like this:

```
public static Dog ConvertTo(this Animal animal)
{
    Dog concreteAnimal;
    if (animal.Name == "tom")
    {
        concreteAnimal = new Tiger(); // compiler error at this line
    }
    return concreteAnimal;
}
```

The user asked for a `Dog`, but you're trying to assign a `Tiger` and return it.  You can't do that because a `Tiger` is not a `Dog`.

Answer (score 1):

> Why is the compiler not able to convert Tiger(this class implemented IAnimal) to TAnimal. This seems to be a problem while using generic constraints.

I think the other answers have addressed *why* your code won't work as written. However, here's an example of how to accomplish what I *think* you're after. With this extension method, the caller explicitly states which implementation of `IAnimal` they want to convert* to. The `TOut` parameter is constrained so that it has a parameterless constructor, so I can create a new instance of it and copy over the values from the original `animal` instance. If anything, this might give you some food for thought. Hope that helps!

* The word "convert" is a little misleading here. We're definitely not converting anything here.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Dog d = new Dog { Age = 37, Name = "Nick" };
        Tiger t = d.ConvertTo<Dog, Tiger>();
        Debug.Assert(t.Name == d.Name);
        Debug.Assert(t.Age == d.Age);
    }
}

static class AnimalExtension
{
    public static TOut ConvertTo<TIn, TOut>(this TIn animal) 
        where TIn : IAnimal 
        where TOut : IAnimal, new()
    {
        TOut convertedAnimal = new TOut
        {
            Age = animal.Age,
            Name = animal.Name
        };

        return convertedAnimal;
    }
}

interface IAnimal
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    int Age { get; set; }
}

class Tiger : IAnimal
{
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class Dog : IAnimal
{
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```